# Can't delete file because my program still has it open

Tags: vb.net, file-io, syncfusion

I have a program the grabs PDF files and merges them, then deletes the original unmerged files to the recycle bin.

I've been reworking the program to take advantage of the Syncfusion PDF tools, and it's been mostly going smooth, right up until I try to delete the file.

The warning popup tells me that it is my program that has the file open, but I'm not sure where it's still open at in the program or how to find out.

here's the function:

```
Function MergePDFSync(ByVal Path As String, ByVal SavePath As String, ByVal outFileName As String, ByVal DeleteOriginal As Boolean) As String
    On Error GoTo sError

    Dim CreateDate As Date = Now
    Dim finalFileName As String = ""
    Dim dInfo As New DirectoryInfo(Path)

    If dInfo.GetFiles("*.pdf").Length > 0 Then
        Dim doc As New Syncfusion.Pdf.PdfDocument
        Dim ldoc As Syncfusion.Pdf.Parsing.PdfLoadedDocument
        Dim file As String

        For Each f As FileInfo In dInfo.GetFiles("*.pdf")
            ldoc = New Syncfusion.Pdf.Parsing.PdfLoadedDocument(f.OpenRead)
            Syncfusion.Pdf.PdfDocument.Merge(doc, ldoc)
            ldoc.Close()
            doc.DisposeOnClose(ldoc)
        Next
        ldoc = Nothing

        finalFileName = Format(CreateDate, "M-d-yy-HHmmss-") & outFileName

        doc.Save(Path & "\" & finalFileName)
        doc.Close()
        doc = Nothing

        dInfo = Nothing

        If DeleteOriginal Then ' delete origional files
            dInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Path)
            For Each f As FileInfo In dInfo.GetFiles("*.pdf") 'For i As Integer = 0 To strFiles.Length - 1 ' run through all the files in the directory
                Console.WriteLine("MergePDF2 10.1 : " & f.Name & " = " & finalFileName)
                If Not f.Name = finalFileName Then
                    Console.WriteLine("MergePDF2 10.2 : Delete " & f.FullName)
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(f.FullName, FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If

    Return finalFileName
    Exit Function
sError:
    ReportError("MergePDF2 " & Path & " " & Err.Description)
    Console.WriteLine("MergePDF2 " & Path & " " & ErrorToString())
End Function
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# File Exception: cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701685/c-sharp-file-exception-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-anoth) and about a dozen others (open the link I provided, and see the long list of "Related" questions to the right of it). Please search this site for the error message you're receiving, as chances are very good the question has been asked (and answered) here before, and one of them can answer the question for you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Ken, except that I tried all those things first. The problem was apparently related to how .Close works on a Syncfusion PDFLoadedDocument. See the_lotus' helpful answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know they had a problem with the merge function, I'm not sure if it's fix or which version you are using. You might want to try alternative to merge.

```
Dim docTarget As PdfLoadedDocument = New PdfLoadedDocument(targetFile)
Dim docAppend As PdfLoadedDocument = New PdfLoadedDocument(appendFile)

docTarget.Append(docAppend)
docTarget.Save()
docTarget.Close(True)
docAppend.Close(True)
```

http://www.syncfusion.com/support/forums/pdf-windows/79124

or add pages one by one

```
doc.Pages.Add(ldoc.Pages[i]);
```

http://www.syncfusion.com/support/kb/876/How%20to%20merge%20two%20PDF%20documents

Comment: I left my code as it was except that I changed ldoc to .Close(True) and it worked. Merge thankfully wasn't the problem, just that the stream wasn't closing along with the loadeddocument. Good find, +1!